# Folder picker on web application in Django Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to integrate a folder picker on my web application such that when the user uploads a folder, I should be able to retrieve all the files inside it to perform some processing on it.

To my knowledge, we CANNOT directly select the folder from web application HTML front end (unlike a file) via simply adding a button for upload (please correct me if I am mistaken here)
Thus, I figured out a workaround by integrating JavaScript snippet to my HTML webpage.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio (VS code) to code this.

This is what I have tried. I am providing all the required snippets that can be directly used to mimic this scenario:

In "**folder_processing.html**" :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Scan Files</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b> SELECT THE FOLDER FROM CHOOSER BELOW: </B>
<br>

<form id="scanForm" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="text" id="folderPathInput" name="folder_path" required readonly>
         <button type="button" id="selectFolderBtn">Select Folder</button>
         <button type="submit" name="folder_submit">Scan Folder</button>
</form>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#selectFolderBtn').click(function() {
                // Open a file input dialog to select a file
                $('<input type="file" id="folderInput" style="display:none;">').change(function() {
                    var folderPath = $(this).val();
                    if (folderPath) {
                        // Set the selected folder path in the input field
                        $('#folderPathInput').val(folderPath);
                    }
                }).click();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In "**urls.py**" file of my application:

```
from django.urls import path
from sample_app import views 
# NOTE: sample_app is the name of the application I have used in Django web app. Pls replace it with your project application name which you have kept.

urlpatterns = [
    path("folder/", views.process_folder, name="process_folder")
]
```

In views.py file, here is the "process_folder()" :

```
def process_folder(request):
    print(request.method) # This is printing GET
    if ((request.method == 'POST') and ('folder_submit' in request.POST)):
        folder_path = request.POST.get('folder_path')
        if folder_path:
            file_paths = scan_folder(folder_path)
            for file_path in file_paths:
                # Do something with each file path
                print(file_path)
            return HttpResponse("File scanning complete.")
    
    return HttpResponse("Invalid request.")

def scan_folder(folder_path):
    file_paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    return file_paths
```

Now, when you start the server using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and then try to run **127.0.0.1:8000/folder/** on your browser, it returns "Invalid request" as HttpResponse i.e. the control is not going inside the condition --

```
if ((request.method == 'POST') and ('folder_submit' in request.POST)) 
# This condition is written in process_folder() function
```

Moreover on further investigation, when I printed `print(request.method) #` added as first line of the `process_folder()` function, it returned 'GET'. That's why its not getting inside that if condition and thus, couldn't get folder explorer.

Can someone please explain how to fix this issue and retrieve the folder using upload from the end user via front end folder explorer in Django web application?

Comment: is it because you are missing `action=""` in your `<form>` tag?